# I can't see MySQL in datasource list for entity framework

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I use visual studio 2010-12 and I installed  [ADO.NET Entity Framework 4.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18504) , [Mysql .Net Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) and [Mysql Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench)

Before formatting, my computer, I could use entity framework for MySQL. but not I cant see MySQL in data source list. Here is what I mean

[image: entity list]

Well...where is the my mistake or missing?

Comment: Okay I solved, I opened server explorer and I connected to mysql database, after I tried to add an ado.net entity framework object and it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved, I opened server explorer and I connected to mysql database, after I tried to add an ado.net entity framework object and it works

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstall existing mysqlconnector.
Download mysqlconnector/net 6.5.6
It works with VS2010 on my desktop. 
However, id you're using vs2012, you may try the 
latest version.